# Getting a `die` message every time the user tries to create a new file

Tags: php, file, radio-button, subscribe

I am doing a PHP assignment and am collecting information about a user and storing it in a file depending on if the user Subscribes or not. **Disclaimer:** I know it is better to do this stuff in a database and using mySQL, but we haven't learned it yet and are told to use PHP. I have radio buttons that determine whether to subscribe or unsubscribe. Here those are

```
<input type="radio" name="sub" value="subscribe" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="sub" value="unsubscribe" />
```

I have the subscribed one to be checked by default. I get the result of the radio button in the variable `$Action` listed below. For some reason though, any time I try to "subscribe" I always get the `die` message, "Unable to create file!" and I am not sure why I am getting it. Here is my code below.

```
$Name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$EmailAddress = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailaddress']);
$Action = $_POST['sub'];

if($EmailAddress == "") {
   print "<p>Error. No email address. Please try again.</p>";
   $move = 0;
} else {
   $move = 1;
}

if($move) {
   // If the user subscribes, make a file for them.
   if($Action == "subscribe") {
     // Create a file for each user saved as their email address.
     $myfile = fopen($_POST['emailaddress'] . ".txt", "w") or die("Unable to create file!");
     $txt = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n";    // Add the name to the file
     fwrite($myfile, $txt);
     $txt = "Email Address: " . $_POST['emailaddress'] . "\n";    // Add the email address to the file
     fwrite($myfile, $txt);

     // Check which preferences are set. Add to file if they are checked.
     if(isset($_POST['compositions'])) {
        $txt = "Preference: " . $_POST['compositions'] . "\n";    // Add the first preference to the file if checked
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
     }

     if(isset($_POST['marchingband'])) {
        $txt = "Preference: " . $_POST['marchingband'] . "\n";    // Add the second preference to the file if checked
     }

     if(isset($_POST['projects'])) {
        $txt = "Preference: " . $_POST['projects'] . "\n";    // Add the third preference to the file if checked
     }

     if(isset($_POST['events'])) {
        $txt = "Preference: " . $_POST['events'] . "\n";    // Add the fourth preference to the file is checked
     }

     fclose($myfile);

     print "<p>Thank you for subscribing!</p>";
  } else {
     // If a user unsubscribes, delete their file.
     unlink($_POST['emailaddress'] . ".txt");
     print "<p>You have successfully unsubscribed.</p>";
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting the error message every time when I am filling out all the required fields like I am supposed to? Thanks.

Comment: it is very bad idea to create file with the name posted by user, it is security hole, also - in what folder this file will be created?

Comment: I know it is a bad idea, that's why I said in the disclaimer it is better to do this in a database or mySQL.... How do I dictate where the files will be stored?

Comment: fopen first argument is used to say where to store file

Comment: I thought that was the name of the file? So would I need to make a folder called, `myfile`?

Comment: you need to provide absolute path to file, like `/tmp/myfolder/$EmailAddress.txt`

Comment: Would I do that with `..`? For instance `fopen("../tmp/myfolder/$EmailAddress.txt", "w");`?

Comment: don't use `..` because you don't know what folder is current

Comment: I specified the absolute path and it still wont work.

Comment: @Lashane I am putting the absolute path in and it still won't work. Any idea why?

Comment: do you have rights to write in your folder?

Comment: How would I check to see if I do?

Comment: try to create file from console, don't forget that php user is usually different one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107058/discussion-between-genericuser01-and-lashane).